# Finding vowels in user input array

Tags: c++, arrays

// I am new to c++ and I don't understand all of the syntax rules and how certain things like pointers behave. I want to know about how to make a program to find the vowels in an input **array**, no vectors suggestions please. I know I may be doing this the hard way but I want to know the why and how of things better.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    char vowels[6] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
    char *word = NULL;
    cout << "Enter word" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 6; j++) 
            if(word[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                sum++;
            } 
        cout << sum;
    } 
    delete [] word;
    word = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to enter the word (`cin >> n` does not do it).

Comment: do you want a total count or count for each vowel? Could you give an example input with the example desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the inputted value into word and you print the sum after each letter because you're printing inside of the loop that goes through the word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of few things in your program segment.

1. You need to create a char array (e.g word[20]) for reading the string.
2. You need to read line into the char array and not to int (`cin >> n;`).
3. You cant read in a string using 'cin'.
4. you need to print sum (no. of vowels) outside loop.

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       int sum = 0;
       int n;
       char vowels[6] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
       char word[20] = NULL;
       cout << "Enter word" << endl;
       while (getline(cin, word)) //read line of text including white space until enter key is pressed
       {

       }
       n=strlen(word);      //get the length of the input string  
       for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j < 6; j++) 
               if(word[i] == vowels[j])
               {
                   sum++;
               }      
       } 
       cout << sum;   //Print total number of vowles
       delete [] word;
       word = NULL;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   This would generate desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes in your code:

Firstly, `cin >> word` does not take a word as input, it only takes a *number*. This is because `word` is of type `int`.

Also, you need to print `sum` outside the for loop so that it is not continuously printed.